# What is minimal configuration needed for .net Windows Azure WebApp work with cshtml?

Tags: c#, azure, razor, azure-web-app-service

I want to develop a .net application that would have a simple one index.cshtml in it. Azure WebApp supports CI so I have puted my index.cshtml into github project. No .sln, no visual studio files - pure one text file (as if say I'm on console linux with only nano and git). I changed Default documents in WebApp to index.cshtml, provided path to directory with site contents.

Yet I do see
`You do not have permission to view this directory or page.` on [`/`](http://apmath4oj.azurewebsites.net/) page and

> Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because
>   it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be
>   incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is
>   spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /index.cshtml

if I try to go to index [directly](http://apmath4oj.azurewebsites.net/index.cshtml).

So what is required besides my index.cshtml file for [my WebApp](https://github.com/OlegJakushkin/AzureWebAppTest/tree/master/site) to work?

Comment: I do this all the time and it works fine.  Do you have anything interesting in your web.config?

Comment: @ChrisGillum: added [web.config](https://github.com/OlegJakushkin/AzureWebAppTest/blob/0f8d7adfaa6f1365a42b468d6576288dbd1a4fce/site/web.config) - nothing changed=(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to add the following `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webPages:Version" value="1.0"/>
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Technically, the `<system.web>` section is optional, but will help you debug issues.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add a second answer, because I looked at your site and you are having a different issue that a web.config won't fix.

By default, the site's physical root is the `site\wwwroot` folder. In your case, you have your files in a `site` subfolder under that, so they're in `site\wwwroot\site`. But looking at your site configuration, you have mapped the site root to be just `site`, so it's not pointing where it should.

So just change the mapping to go to `site\wwwroot\site` instead of `site`, and things should work a lot better.

As an alternative, you can keep the default `site\wwwroot`, and instead use [this technique](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-folder-for-a-node-php-or-aspnet-site) to set `project = MyWebRoot` in your `.deployment` file.